# Jasypt encrypted field and Criteria API not getting results (Grails)

Tags: grails, encryption

I just started playing with Grails and working on simple registration/login feature.
I have this simple domain object:

```
class Person {

    String firstName, lastName, email
    String login, password

    static constraints = {
        firstName nullable: true
        lastName nullable: true
    }
    static mapping = {
        password type: GormEncryptedStringType
    }
}
```

I am saving Person object just fine. But then when I try to retrieve it for login purposes using Criteria API, it won't find it:

```
def criteria = Person.createCriteria()
def person = criteria.get {
    and {
        eq("login", params.login)
        eq("password", params.password)
    }
}
```

If I remove `eq("password", params.password)` or change it to something not encrypted it works just fine. Anyone have an idea how to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong (security). You don't encrypt passwords, you hash them. Hashing is one-way and lossy, whereas encryption is two-way and lossless, but if you can decrypt the passwords then you're vulnerable to attackers who gain access to the decryption keys, and then they'll be able to decrypt them too.

If you use hashing, then you can (but of course shouldn't) let anyone view the hashed passwords because they're useless if you use a good hashing scheme. Bcrypt is one of the best and is easy to use.

Instead of decrypting the stored encrypted password to verify a cleartext password from a user authentication attempt, you should hash the supplied password and validate it against the stored *hashed* password. For some algorithms this is a simple as checking that the values are the same, but that's not the case with Bcrypt since the algorithm always generates a different hash for each invocation. But the algorithm can validate two hashed passwords, so that's not a problem.

So the real fix to your problem is to stop using encryption, and stop 'rolling your own' security. [spring-security-core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) is a popular option.